# SQL Server outbound IP address inconsistency in Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machines, azure-networking

I have this setup:

- Azure VM (B-series)
- Static public IP
- SQL Server running outside of Azure, with IP whitelisting on the firewall set tot he public static IP of the Azure VM
- Two ASP.NET apps that connect to the SQL Server on the same IP but with different usernames/passwords

Expected:

- Both apps can connect to the SQL Server and return data

Actual:

- Only one of them can connect to the SQL Server and return data
- Apps running elsewhere with static whitelisted IPs can connect just fine

This is really wierd!  Does Azure sometimes use some other outbound IP address?

Comment: If you have a static, public IP assigned to the VM then this should be used for all outbound traffic. Are  you sure your error is a firewall one?

Comment: Not 100% sure it is firewall, but here is another symptom.  I put the credentials from the application that does connect into SQL Server management studio inside this VM and SSMS fails to connect, while the app using the same credentials connects OK. Something is clearly very wierd with this VM.

Comment: What are the DB credential? Server level users or DB? If they are DB only then you will need to select the DB in SSMS before you can login.

Comment: Thanks!  They are DB level.  How would I select the DB in SSMS?  Is that in Advanced?

Comment: Yes go to advanced settings and the first option there is to select a DB.